# Unable to get the Suggester Response from Solrj

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I am trying to fetch suggester response from Solr using java,but I am unable to get the resposne everytime when I run the code.
Code:

```
     SolrClient solrClient=new HttpSolrClient.Builder("http://localhost:/solr/core/").build();
     SolrQuery sq = new SolrQuery();
           sq.setRequestHandler("/suggest");
            sq.set("suggest","true");
            sq.set("suggest.build","true");
            sq.set("suggest.dictionary","mySuggester");
            sq.set("suggest.q",name);
    QueryResponse rsp = solrClient.query(sq);
            System.out.println(rsp.getSuggesterResponse().getSuggestedTerms());
            List<String> types=rsp.getSuggesterResponse().getSuggestedTerms().get("mySuggester");
            System.out.println(types);
```

But when I run the query url in Solr UI  using:
 http://localhost:8983/solr/core/suggest?suggest.dictionary=mySuggester&suggest.q=stack&suggest=true&wt=json ,I get the output in the form of(example) :

```
{"responseHeader":{"status":0,"QTime":119},"suggest":{"mySuggester":{"stack":{"numFound":2,"suggestions":[{"term":"<b>Stack</b>overfolw","weight":0,"payload":""},{"term":"<b>Stack</b>overfolw advanced","weight":0,"payload":""}]}}}}
```

When i use the solrJ code to fetch the suggested terms I get [**Stack**overfolw advanced,**Stack**overfolw advanced] and some times just [].

I am not understanding why this issue occurs.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like you have suggest.build as 'true' in your SolrJ code. It's probably timing out while trying to build the suggester index.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Can u explain how to solve the issue.

Comment: Try removing `sq.set("suggest.build","true");` from the the SolrJ code and see if you have the same issue. You should build the suggester index periodically depending on how often your Solr index is updated, but not on a regular query.

Comment: I tried the alternative,but still the problem persists.The response doesnt have the terms,but the Solr UI has the terms in response.

Comment: FWIW. What I do in similar situations is find a way to get the query (from code) on the command line or find in a log file and then I compare.  Often I find that the way I thought I was building the query is not actually what I see when I print to the command line or see it in a log file.  Can you post both the URL from the UI and the string that results from the code to this page?  (I see a URL line above and if it's the same, then that will be good for comparison.)  You might try tail -f on the solr log file before triggering the code and I think you'll see it come through there...

Comment: The query string is : qt=/suggest&suggest=true&suggest.build=true&suggest.dictionary=mySuggester&suggest.q="stack"

Comment: I got the solution.The query was with in double quotes.It has to be sugge‌​st.q=stack.